# php array combine

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, concatenation

I have the next array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 160
            [payment_period] => Monthly
            [plan_payment_type_id] => 171
            [payment_type_id] => 4
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 160
            [payment_period] => Monthly
            [plan_payment_type_id] => 172
            [payment_type_id] => 5
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 161
            [payment_period] => Weekly
            [plan_payment_type_id] => 173
            [payment_type_id] => 9
        )
)
```

I need to group this array by id. How can I do it in the best way?
My output should be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 160
            [payment_period] => Monthly
            [payment_types] => Array(
                [0] => Array(
                    [plan_payment_type_id] => 171
                    [payment_type_id] => 4
                )
                [1] => Array(
                    [plan_payment_type_id] => 172
                    [payment_type_id] => 5
                )
            )
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 161
            [payment_period] => Weekly
            [payment_types] => Array(
                [0] => Array(
                    [plan_payment_type_id] => 173
                    [payment_type_id] => 9
                )
            )
        )
)
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Two things: what happens if two elements have the same id but different payment period? Also maybe you should consider ditching arrays for objects in this case? When you get to 3d arrays your code visibility starts to deteriorate.

Comment: If `id` the same, other elements will be the same too except `plan_payment_type_id` and `payment_type_id`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$output = array();
$id_array = array();
$i = 0;
foreach($input as $key=>$val) {
        if(array_key_exists($val['id'],$id_array)) {
                $pos = $id_array[$val['id']];
                $output[$pos]['payment_types'][] = array('plan_payment_type_id'=> $val['plan_payment_type_id'],'payment_type_id' => $val['payment_type_id']);
        } else {
                $output[$i] = array('id' => $val['id'],'payment_period' => $val['payment_period'],'payment_types' => array(array('plan_payment_type_id'=> $val['plan_payment_type_id'],'payment_type_id' => $val['payment_type_id'])));
                echo "Adding ",$val['id'],"\n";
                $id_array[$val['id']] = $i; 
                $i++;
        }   
}
```

[**Working link**](http://www.ideone.com/01Vb4)

Answer (score 1):

You are stuck because you try to build an enumarated array, when you actually want to *groups this by array id*. Just use the "id" field as target index:

```
foreach ($in as $src) {
    extract($src);
    $output[$id]["id"] = $id;
    $output[$id]["payment_period"] = $payment_period;
    $output[$id]["payment_types"][] = array(
        "plan_payment_type_id" => $plan_payment_type_id,
        "payment_type_id" => $payment_type_id,
    );
}
```

Of course you can use lengthy $src[] variable names instead of the evil extract() shortcut.

Anyway, this method groups your output array by $id, but also retains the "id"=>$id internal key.